# Strange UIView sizes after orientation has been changed

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, orientation

I make a log from the sizes of the main view, and I experienced strange sizes at `orientation=4` on the log. I could not figure out what the problem is. Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationDidChange:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];

}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}

- (void)orientationDidChange:(NSNotification *)note
{
    int orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    NSLog(@"orientation=%i -------------------------------",orientation);
    CGRect f = self.view.frame;                     NSLog(@"self.view.frame =(%f, %f, %f, %f)",f.origin.x, f.origin.y, f.size.width, f.size.height);
    f = self.view.bounds;                           NSLog(@"self.view.bounds=(%f, %f, %f, %f)",f.origin.x, f.origin.y, f.size.width, f.size.height);
    f = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];   NSLog(@"main.app.frame  =(%f, %f, %f, %f)",f.origin.x, f.origin.y, f.size.width, f.size.height);
    f = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];             NSLog(@"main.bounds     =(%f, %f, %f, %f)",f.origin.x, f.origin.y, f.size.width, f.size.height);

}
```

The results are the following:

```
orientation=1 -------------------------------
self.view.frame =(0.000000, 20.000000, 320.000000, 460.000000)
self.view.bounds=(0.000000, 0.000000, 320.000000, 460.000000)
main.app.frame  =(0.000000, 20.000000, 320.000000, 460.000000)
main.bounds     =(0.000000, 0.000000, 320.000000, 480.000000)

orientation=0 -------------------------------
self.view.frame =(0.000000, 20.000000, 320.000000, 460.000000)
self.view.bounds=(0.000000, 0.000000, 320.000000, 460.000000)
main.app.frame  =(0.000000, 20.000000, 320.000000, 460.000000)
main.bounds     =(0.000000, 0.000000, 320.000000, 480.000000)

orientation=4 -------------------------------
self.view.frame =(0.000000, 20.000000, 320.000000, 460.000000) <== First time size
self.view.bounds=(0.000000, 0.000000, 320.000000, 460.000000) <== First time size
main.app.frame  =(0.000000, 20.000000, 320.000000, 460.000000) <== First time size
main.bounds     =(0.000000, 0.000000, 320.000000, 480.000000) <== First time size

orientation=2 -------------------------------
self.view.frame =(20.000000, 0.000000, 300.000000, 480.000000)
self.view.bounds=(0.000000, 0.000000, 480.000000, 300.000000)
main.app.frame  =(20.000000, 0.000000, 300.000000, 480.000000)
main.bounds     =(0.000000, 0.000000, 320.000000, 480.000000)

orientation=4 -------------------------------
self.view.frame =(20.000000, 0.000000, 300.000000, 480.000000) <== Why is it different?
self.view.bounds=(0.000000, 0.000000, 480.000000, 300.000000) <== Why is it different?
main.app.frame  =(20.000000, 0.000000, 300.000000, 480.000000) <== Why is it different?
main.bounds     =(0.000000, 0.000000, 320.000000, 480.000000) <== Why is it different?
```

The steps I took to get this problem are the following:

```
- cmd+right arrow
- cmd+right arrow
- cmd+left arrow
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not supporting orientation UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown (i.e. orientation 4).

Therefore, the view should not rotate when the device is UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown.

Notice how when you rotate to orientation 4, the values are exactly the same as the previous orientation's dimensions.

To fix this:

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}
```

And make sure you have upside down selected as well for your support device orientation.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want to support the UpsideDown orientation. The additional UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown not solve the problem

Comment: Your problem was that you could not figure out what was making the strange sizes. It was because it did not support orientation 4, therefore even if you tried rotating, the values will still be the previous orientation. It may be less obvious on simulator. But on device, you can try physically turning your device upside down but the UI rotation will not be invoked. 
Essentially, no UI will be updated when moving to orientation 4 because it is not supported.

Comment: Dear TreeTree, I don't know what i has been misunderstood, but I added the UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown for the supportedInterfaceOrientations method, checked all of options on the "Supported Interface Orientations" under the "project summary", and it worked as same way.

Comment: It seems always inherit the previous orientation's values.

Comment: Can you add something to the UIView, eg a button. And see if the button rotates as well at UpsideDown.

Comment: Hello, Still not, I tried to make the buttons, but everything is ok with them. We made an app with this code on an another Mac/Xcode, but worked as well. I will update you. Thank you TreeTree!